# C++ Problem on setting the serial com port

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

I having a problem on the setting the serial COM port on my C++ program.
There is my code in below.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<string>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include"SerialPort.h"

char output[MAX_DATA_LENGTH];
char incomingData[MAX_DATA_LENGTH];

char *port = "\\\\.\\COM7";

int main(){
SerialPort arduino(port);
if(arduino.isConnected()){
    cout<<"Connection made"<<endl<<endl;
}
else{
    cout<<"Error in port name"<<endl<<endl;
}
while(arduino.isConnected()){
    cout<<"Enter your command: "<<endl;
    string data;
    cin>>data;

    char *charArray = new char[data.size() + 1];
    copy(data.begin(), data.end(), charArray);
    charArray[data.size()] = '\n';

    arduino.writeSerialPort(charArray, MAX_DATA_LENGTH);
    arduino.readSerialPort(output, MAX_DATA_LENGTH);

    cout<<">> "<<output<<endl;

    delete [] charArray;
    }
return 0;
}
```

There are an error on `"\\\\.\\COM7"`

showing an error message `a value of type "const char *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "char *"`

When I change it to `const char *port = "\\\\.\\COM7";`

It showing error on `SerialPort arduino(port);`

Please help me. Really need some help on this. Thank you.

Comment: Project > Properties > C/C++ > Language > Conformance mode = "No".

Answer (score 0):

In C++ literal strings are ***constant*** arrays of characters. Therefore you need `const char*` for pointers to them.

If you must pass a non-constant pointer to a function, use *arrays*:

```
char port[] = "\\\\.\\COM7";
```

A possibly better solution would be to modify the `SerialPort` constructor to accept `const char*` as its argument. Or even better to start using `std::string` for strings.